# Number of items purchased per invoice using seaborn and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm using [online retail dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail) and I want to plot the distribution of number of items per invoice number.

[image]

InvoiceNo of type: non-null object

Quantity  of type: non-null int64

How to do that? Also, I didn't know how to filter using pandas operations to get that without visualizations.
like for example if I want to know the quantity per invoice I can do:

```
retail_uk.groupby('InvoiceNo').sum().sort_values(by='Quantity', ascending=False)['Quantity']
```

I need an answer for both:

- How to plot that with Seaborn (more important because it allows me to get a better idea of the distribution) what are the different data transformations needed to achieve that?
- How to do it using groupby of Pandas.

Comment: what does it do? I checked the documention which says : "return the number of elements in the underlying data" what element? I didn't understand. I want to get the number of items purchased in the same invoiceNo. Does the size count the occurrences of each invoiceNo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need aggregate `sum` and for plot [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352/Online%20Retail.xlsx'
retail_uk = pd.read_excel(url)

df = retail_uk.groupby('InvoiceNo', as_index=False)['Quantity'].sum()
#if want sorting
df = df.sort_values(by='Quantity', ascending=False)
print (df.head())

ax = sns.barplot(x="InvoiceNo", y="Quantity", data=df)
```

Comment: I need to plot:  the number of items per invoice distribution. this plots the quantity per invoice, it's not the same thing because it can be quantity/invoice of the one item. and me I'm interested in knowing how many items a customer buy in a transaction.

Comment: I think you need [countplot, ax = sns.countplot(x="InvoiceNo", data=retail_uk)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), then groupby should be omit

Comment: Now I am on phone only, so untested. But if need sorting, then use `df = retail_uk['InvoiceNo'].value_counts().reset_index()`

Comment: I check it again and it seems you need `ax = sns.countplot(x="InvoiceNo", hue="StockCode", data=retail_uk)` - and in pandas it is `df.groupby(['InvoiceNo', 'StockCode']).size()`.

Comment: Also i check `df = retail_uk.InvoiceNo.value_counts().rename_axis('InvoiceNo').reset_index(name='count')` but there is `25900` rows so a bit problematic plot it- to much data.

Comment: If the rows are too big, it's better to avoid doing visualizations?

Comment: Hmm, hard question for me. I am not such expert for this limits, but if many data plot is possible, but need more time and output should be not so nice (e.g. too thick bars...).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the number of rows for each unique InvoiceNo, you can do

```
df.groupby('InvoiceNo').size()
```

If you want to group all the unique InvoiceNo's together and sum the 'Quantity' rows within each group, you do

```
df.groupby('InvoiceNo').agg(np.sum)['Quantity']
```